# How were reputation points calculated in this instance?

Tags: support, reputation

I can't figure out how my reputation points were calculated for a specific answer. [Here's the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032032/how-do-i-compute-the-non-client-window-size-in-wpf/6032318#6032318).

It looks like I got three upvotes and had it marked as an accepted answer. So I'd expect 45 points total? But I have 39 points, split up as +10, +10, +15, +4 when I look at my reputation page.

I tried looking at the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) but didn't see anything about how your rep can go up by 4 points.

I honestly don't care about the 6 points, I'm just new to the whole SO thing and trying to get a feel for how everything works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you were near the reputation cap (200) when the last upvote happened.

If you had 196 reputation earned that day, you cannot go past 200, and would explain the +4 (reputation for accepted answers are not counted in the cap)

Comment: Yep, that appears to be what happened. Thanks!